# Flutter: Error compiling iOS app on CodeMagic, 'file_picker' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, filepicker, podfile, codemagic

I don't own a Mac and am compiling by CodeMagic, but I'm trying to solve this problem early on, i've done everything but the same thing happens all the time.

On Android it works fine.

Can anyone help me?

> /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module 'file_picker' not found
> @import file_picker;
> ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.

Below is my Podfile...

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

end
```

File_picker version in my pubspec.yaml file

`file_picker: ^4.6.1`

Comment: Using Flutter 3.7.1 on a local macmini, I created a new project using `flutter create` and then ran it, then added the `file_picker: ^4.6.1` and ran the app again and it still built and ran successfully. I then pushed it to Github & built on Codemagic also successfully. Could you try doing that to check that its actually the file_picker pkg causing the error?